# Android Passing a URI pointing to an image file to another activity not in the app module and deleting the file afterwards possible?

Tags: android, file, uri, mediastore, android-storage

I'm trying to avoid `TransactionTooLargeException` by writing an image byteArray into a file created in
`context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.Directory_PICTURES)`, generating a URI from it, and passing the URI from the host app activity into another activity that resides outside of the host app module, perhaps from another dependency AAR. Once the 2nd activity is done retrieving the byteArray string from the file using the URI, I would like to delete the file as I don't have any more use for it and it is imperative that I delete it.

I modified the sample code for generating an image JPEG file here:

```
private fun createImageFile(flag: Boolean): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val prefixName = if(flag) "StringA" else "StringB"
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${prefixName}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        )
    }
```

Here is my code for writing to the file.

```
val photoFile = createImageFile(flag).also {
      photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@AppHostActivity,"com.mydomain.fileprovider", it)
}
fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(photoFile).apply {
      this.write(imageByteArray)
}
```

I pass `photoURI` into an intent bundle to the next activity not in the host app module, and from this activity, I would like to delete the imageFile from the app's storage defined by `context.getExternalFileDir(Environment.Directory_PICTURES)`.
And this is where I'm stuck right now.

I have yet to look into `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`, or into `MediaStore API`. I'm targetting Android 13 as well and I believe there have been some restrictions to reading and writing app storage in Android around Android 10.

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to delete the imageFile when I'm not in the host activity module and with only the URI for the file?

Comment: I'm not getting your use case exactly but have you though about developing one cron job which will be activated everyday once(may be) and delete all those unnecessary files ?  because there is no direct way to get a callback from other application

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid TransactionTooLargeException by writing an image byteArray into a file" -- why not just *carefully* share it via a singleton cache?

Comment: Believe it or not, I do have the singleton approach working as a last resort. But I would like to see if I can get this approach working if possible.

Comment: The use case is because the captured image can contain sensitive information, and I don't wanna run the risk of storing those into the application just to pass the image to another activity in another module. Unless there is a way to have a shared view model between the two activities residing in different modules.